Vite not rendering when Import not used
I'm switching crt to vite react now I have imported a component but haven't used it yet, due to this empty import the page is not rendering. Also errors don't show as it would in CRT
When I removed the component it worked but this should not usually effect the rendering and the project that I'm migrating has many empty imports as I was trying different things.

Your linter might be showing these as unused imports. Not sure though. Can you share the error message?
